# Can't get all id in php which loop using jquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting all keywords from mysql database in html table row. So When I click on each keyword it's calling `keywordBox`id using jquery to add `kid` to mysql database using php. I used while loop to get all `kid` but I just get only one `kid`. why ? It's should be get different `kid` when i click on different `keyword`

Following is my code:

```
echo "<div id='keywordBox'>";
echo '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1055">';
$count = 0;
while($result =  mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  if($count%6==0 && $count!=0)
    echo '</tr><tr>';
  elseif($count==0) echo '<tr>';

    $kid = $result['kid'];
    $keywordName = ucfirst($result['keywordName']);

    $keyword_short_name = ucfirst($result['keyword_short_name']); 
    $keyword_full_name = ucfirst($result['keyword_full_name']); 

    echo "<input type='hidden' id='kid' value='$kid'/>";    
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='cdid' value='$cdid'/>";  
    echo "<td width='400'><strong>$keyword_full_name</strong><strong>($keyword_short_name)</strong><br/>$keywordName</td>";

    $count++;  
}
echo '</table>';
echo "</div";


<script>
$('#keywordBox').click(function(e) {

    var kid = $('#kid').val();       
    var cdid = $('#cdid').val();         

     e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"addKeywordProcess.php",
        data:{
            'kid' : kid,
            'cdid' : cdid
        },
        success:function(res){
            $('#result').html(res);         
            }
        }); 
});
</script>
```

**addKeywordProcess.php Code:**

```
<?php
ob_start();
@session_start();
require_once("../config.php");  


if(!isset($_SESSION['front_username']) && isset($_SESSION['front_username']) == "" &&
    !isset($_SESSION['front_password']) && isset($_SESSION['front_password']) == "" &&
     !isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['user_id']) == "") {
    header("Location:login.php");   
    exit();
}


$cdid = (int) $_POST['cdid']; // Get cdid from keyword page.
$kid = (int) $_POST['kid']; // Get cdid from keyword page.

$check =  mysql_query("SELECT cdid, kid FROM userkeywords WHERE kid = '$kid' AND cdid = '$cdid' ");
$num = mysql_num_rows($check);

if($num == 1){
    echo "<div class='error'>Keyword already exits to your contact list. cdid = $cdid and kid = $kid </div>";   
}else{

    $query =  mysql_query("INSERT INTO userkeywords (ukid, cdid, kid) VALUES ('', '$cdid', '$kid') ");
    if($query){
        echo "<div class='success'>Successfully added a new keyowrd to your contact list. </div>";  
    }else{
        echo "<div class='error'>I can't added a new keyword. </div>";  
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: Reading the answers below, your error seems to be an obvious mistake which was obfuscated by mixing your PHP and HTML code together. For future reference, you should separate the HTML template and the PHP script to make your code cleaner and easier to read. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7368842/1031312

Comment: Thanks @Ozzy Important guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are replacing value of `$kid` to

```
echo "<input type='hidden' id='kid' value='$kid'/>";
```

each time, it will contain only the last looped row's value.

Instead of calling the Jquery function on clicking the div, call that function on clicking each tr's.

```
while($result =  mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  if($count%6==0 && $count!=0)
    echo '</tr><tr>';
  elseif($count==0) echo '<tr>';

    $kid = $result['kid'];
    $keywordName = ucfirst($result['keywordName']);

    $keyword_short_name = ucfirst($result['keyword_short_name']); 
    $keyword_full_name = ucfirst($result['keyword_full_name']); 

    echo "<input type='hidden' id='kid' value='$kid'/>";    
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='cdid' value='$cdid'/>";  
    echo "<td width='400' onclick='keywordclick($kid,$cdid)'><strong>$keyword_full_name</strong><strong>($keyword_short_name)</strong><br/>$keywordName</td>";

    $count++;  
    }
```

and change the Jquery function

```
$('#keywordBox').click(function(e) {
----
}
```

to

```
function keywordclick(kid,cid)
{
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"addKeywordProcess.php",
        data:{
            'kid' : kid,
            'cdid' : cid
        },
        success:function(res){
            $('#result').html(res);         
            }
        }); 
}
```

Comment: Then what it's should be ?

Comment: Yes, In while loop I need all Keywords `id` (kid). Then I can get different `kid` when I click on each Keyword name.

Comment: @Shibbir..Please see my updated answer and let me know for any doubts.

Comment: It's showing me `SyntaxError: syntax error
 

keywordclick(55,);

 
`

Comment: sorry it is `$cdid` instead of `$cid`, in hidden field..My mistake

Comment: Ok. It's working now. Can you tell why it's not working in my Code ?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple duplicate ids in your html, which is not valid, as ids must be unique. Simply change to classes, and alter your js accordingly:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' class='kid' value='$kid'/>";    
echo "<input type='hidden' class='cdid' value='$cdid'/>";
```

JS:

```
<script>
$('#keywordBox tr').click(function(e) {

    var kid = $(this).find('.kid').val();       
    var cdid = $(this).find('.cdid').val();         

    ...
```